# Is it possible to have a dynamic character class in lex?

Tags: c++, c, flex-lexer, lex

Can I, for example, set a character class to match a `char*` that can change at runtime? Or are they static and can't change once compiled?

Comment: Lex generates a fixed state machine which internally doesn't have any notion of character class, so I don't think it is possible (unless you delegate matching to a C action, which kind of defies the purpose of lex).

Comment: Yeah, I thought so, thanks!

Comment: Lex *generates* a scanner. It is all done before compile time. *Ergo* not at runtime.